# Logical issue with loops

Tags: java, string, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm making a programm that takes a sentence as input, creates an array of these words and displays wether a word is redundant or isn't.

If "Hello Hi Hello" is scanned, the program should advert the user that there's a redundancy.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sentence ;
    System.out.println("Enter a sentence :");
    sentence = sc.nextLine();
    String[] T = sentence.split(" "); //split the sentence at each " " into an array

    int i=0, o=0 ; //iterators

    boolean b=false; //redundancy condition

    for(String s : T) // for each String of T
    {
        System.out.println("T["+i+"] = "+ s);

        while(b) //while there's no redundancy
        {
            if(o!=i) //makes sure Strings are not at the same index.
            {

                if(s==T[o])
                {
                    b=true; //redundancy is true, while stops
                }
            }
            o++;
        }
        i+=1;
    }

    if(b)   
    {
        System.out.println("There are identical words.");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("There are no identical words.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Whats your question?

Comment: "while(b)" always yields "while(false)", you never enter this loop, b never becomes true .

Comment: I just eddited  if(s.compareTo(T[i]!=0) into f(s.compareTo(T[i]==0)

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code -

```
        while(o<T.length && !b)
        {
            if(o!=i)
            {

                if(s.equals(T[o]))
                {
                    b=true;
                }
            }
            o++;
        }
        i+=1;
    }
```

Comment: doesnt work. 
!b == true, the while loop should stop once b is true.

Comment: if you have boolean b=false before entering loop; as per original question, my solution would work.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed it !

I actually messed with booleans x) I didn't realize that While(false) couldn't loop but While(b==false) could.

```
boolean b=true;
    for(String s : T)
    {
        System.out.println("T["+i+"] = "+ s);
        int o = 0;
        while(b && o<T.length)
        {
            if(o!=i)
            {

                if(s.compareTo(T[o])==0)
                {
                    b=false;
                }
            }
            o+=1;
        }
        i+=1;
    }
```

Thanks guys !